# How to send values from text box through form in "Group Sort Expert"dailogue in crystal report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

[alt text http://img136.imageshack.us/img136/4083/15748429.jpg](http://img136.imageshack.us/img136/4083/15748429.jpg)

Hi all,

Please look into the above screenshot. Here i want to change the value of N in Group Sort Expert explicitly from text box using some c# application.

Can anyone help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that would be very easy. My guess is you'd have to hack into [ReportDocument.ReportDefinition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691433(VS.71).aspx) and maybe somewhere in the Areas or Sections collections. If you did find it and changed the value, you might even have to re-save the .rpt file for it to take effect. I'm not sure if it could be changed on the fly.

Comment: Can you be more specific on this. Because ReportDocument.ReportDefinition is giving irrelevant options.

Comment: ya, I know. It's not made to do this. That's why I said it would be a hack.

Comment: I am a beginner in .net technologies. I dont think i would be able to hack it. Anyways thanks for the answers. If you get any idea could you please post it.